# Can Pandas write lists and dicts as well-formatted JSON blobs in CSV?

Tags: python, pandas

By way of example:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1], 'parsed_json': [[{'a': False}]]})
x.to_csv(index=False)

# Returns:
# id,list_col
# 1,[{'a': False}]
```

Notably, the second column is not valid JSON.  This is an issue for me because `read_sql` automatically parses JSON and other text arrays into Python-native data types.  I've found no way to turn that functionality off, nor to force proper JSON formatting of lists/dicts when writing CSV (which in my opinion would be preferable); if neither can be done, then what read_sql does to JSON isn't invertible without the user writing custom functions.  I've written one that works for my purposes:

```
def rejsonify_df(df):
    if df.shape[0] == 0:
        return df
    cols_to_json = [c for c in df.columns
                    if isinstance(df[c][0], dict)
                    or isinstance(df[c][0], list)]
    df[cols_to_json] = [df[c].to_json() for c in cols_to_json]
    return df

rejsonify_df(x).to_csv(index=False)
```

But a native solution would be much better.  I'd be surprised if I'm the first or last person to run into this issue, and I'm curious whether there's something better out there.

Comment: My `pandas.read_sql` does not parse JSON. Regarding `Series.to_json` how is it not native enough?

Comment: What versions?  I'm on Python 3.6.1 / Pandas 0.22.0.


As far as "not native enough", if multiple people have to contend with this exact issue, having them all come up with their own workarounds is inefficient and error-prone.  As it is, my workaround plays havoc with memory (I welcome suggestions here), which natively implemented JSON conversion could avoid more easily.  Also, more abstractly, it's simply good design to have functions relating to ETL be as easily interoperable / invertible as possible (without custom user shenanigans).

Comment: OK, it's parsing Postgres `jsonb` fields.  I can work around this by casting them to `varchar` in my select, but I'd still think there's discussion to be had about getting `to_csv` to format lists and dicts as JSON (if this discussion has been had, I'd be curious as to the reasons against that functionality).

Comment: You could do it with `to_string()` using `json.dumps()` in the `formatters` keyword but for whatever reason `to_csv()` does not have such a keyword. Probably it should, if only for consistency.

Comment: It should be invertible across the same driver. If you re-dump to SQL it's reasonable to expect it to just work. But you can't have invertibility across different serialization drivers because they have different types. The best you can do is have an intermediate representation (Python native types) with sane defaults for each serializer. Having type mappings across all drivers would be m*n^2 where n is the number of drivers, m the number of types, it's just unmanageable.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16840

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pandas itself is doing the JSON parsing. I looked at the source code for read_sql and I don't see it.

[pandas sql.py source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7c7bd569ce8e0f117c618d068e3d2798134dbc73/pandas/io/sql.py)

Either the database driver or SQLAlchemy is doing it. I'm guessing the database driver. All pandas see are the Python native types.

What you're asking - automatically serialize data that came from JSON back to JSON - sounds simple but it's a bit tricky. The dataframe would have to track metadata on where the data came from. And then you have to answer questions like, should a postgres hstore column, which is loaded as a dict, be serialized back to JSON by to_csv?

In general it would get horribly complicated to try to automatically manage type conversions across all the different serialization schemas supported by pandas. I think pandas is doing the right thing here by not trying to be too smart about it.

If I were you I might just convert all columns to JSON, depending on what else is in the file. After all you can represent numbers and strings in JSON too, not just lists and dicts.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thoughtful & insightful commentary!  It hadn't occurred to me that such parsing would happen driver-side, and the logistics of pandas/driver type mappings do indeed sound impracticable.  A priori it seemed odd to me that writing to CSV (leaving the SQL stuff out of this) lists & dicts wouldn't be serialized as JSON, and given many SQL distros' support for JSON fields it seems like it could be a useful option; but I imagine there are good reasons for the decisions that have been made (curious as always but understanding if I don't get an answer here!)

Comment: (To be clear, I meant the a priori comment as a reflection on where my mind was, which could ultimately be ignored.  However, I do think that an option may be a useful thing...).

Comment: I think they just went for the simple-stupid solution of writing 'repr' or 'string' representations, not sure which it is. Writing JSON representations (or at least having the option) doesn't sound insane, but doing it by default raises some issues too - what if in a column you have both dicts and non JSON serializable structures? What if you have dicts and strings? Do you JSON everything or just the dicts? Etc. I think they just leave those questions to the user because it's use-case specific, so unfortunately you have to write custom code for your use case.